# Modular Exponentiation $a^n \bmod10$ for $a=\{2,3,...,9\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$a^n\bmod 10\;$ for $a=\{2, 3,..., 9\}$

For $a=3,7,9$     I can use Euler's theorem but what about the rest.

I can see the patterns but how can I use those patterns as a proof?

Note: I can't use the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: What is $n$ here?

Comment: $6^2\equiv6\pmod{10}$ so $6^n\equiv6$; same with $5$

Comment: $4\equiv-6\pmod{10}$ so $4^n\equiv(-1)^n6\pmod{10}$

Comment: The order is simply related to the number of values having there gcd for a maximum cycle length. dividing by it we can then do arithmetic in a lower mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

It can be done by a really obvious induction – or simply saying you work in the ring $\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z$.

Also, you can shorten the determination of the patterns.

All these powers $\{ a^n\mid n\in\mathbf N\}$ consist in cycles $\Gamma(a)$ of length $\ell(a)$.  For instance, $\;\Gamma(2)=\{2,4,8,6\}$, so $\ell(2)=4$.

Now, for any power $k$, we have $\;\ell(a^k)=\dfrac{\ell(a)}{\gcd\bigl(k,\ell(a)}$, so

- $\ell(8)=4$. Indeed $\;\Gamma(8)=\{8,4,2,6\}$;
- $\ell(4)=2$:  $\;\Gamma(4)=\{4,6\}$;
- $\ell(6)=\ell(2^4)=1$:  $\;\Gamma(6)=\{6,4\}$.

Comment: `Γ` is just a notation I introduce for convenience in my answer, it has nothing of a standard notation. From my point of view the pattern in obvious (it is enough to mention the recursive definition of a power: $a^{n+1}=a^n$ makes the existence of a cycle obvious as soon as you obtain the same value twice).

Comment: Oh now i got it thanks again